# What is dbms_output.put_line equivalent in MySQL or how to display message in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
USE `doc1vault`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `EIN_ACCESS1`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `doc1vault`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `EIN_ACCESS1`(/*IN my_EIN VARCHAR(350),*/ IN my_ICODesc VARCHAR(200))
    BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE EINLIST varchar(200)  DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM vault_databases where ico_description like CONCAT('%' , my_ICODesc , '%');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
        get_rec:LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO EINLIST;
            IF finished = 1;
        SELECT 'Record Finished'; /*Gives error hewe*/
        LEAVE get_rec;
        END IF;
        END LOOP get_rec;
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

results in

> ERROR 1328 (HY000): Incorrect number of FETCH variables

Comment: The problem is with the cursor. The `FETCH` can not determine the number of variables because it uses a `SELECT *` in the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the solution

```
USE `doc1vault`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `EIN_ACCESS1`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `doc1vault`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `EIN_ACCESS1`(/*IN my_EIN VARCHAR(350),*/ IN my_ICODesc VARCHAR(200))
 BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE EINLIST varchar(400)  DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ico_index FROM vault_databases where 
    ico_description      like CONCAT('%' , my_ICODesc , '%');

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN cur1;
    get_rec:LOOP

        FETCH cur1 INTO EINLIST;

        IF finished = 1 then
            SELECT 'Record Finished';
            LEAVE get_rec;
        END IF;
    END LOOP get_rec;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```